# Maximum number of distinct prime factors of numbers below $2^{64}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

What is the maximum number of distinct prime factors of numbers below $2^{64}$? I'm interested in the exact count, not just an estimate.

In other words, what is the largest $\omega(n)$, where $n < 2^{64}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number with the most distinct prime factors will have the form

$$2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots$$

So all you need is to multiply all primes until you reach $2^{64}$.

Comment: It's 15, in case anyone's wondering... Thanks!

Comment: How did you get 15 @EcirHana ?

Comment: @rsadhvika the product of 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47 is 614889782588491410, which is less than 614889782588491410 ($2^{64}$). Including 53 it is 32589158477190044730.

Comment: @EcirHana Is that a typo?

Comment: @Szeto Sorry, what is a typo?

Comment: Ecir already answered, but one way to show in gp: `vecprod(primes(15)) < 2^64` returns 1, and `vecprod(primes(16)) < 2^64` returns 0.  So the product of the first 15 primes is < $2^{64}$, while the product of the first 16 is > $2^{64}$.